# How do i find the location of a page break in SSRS in RDL source?

Tags: rdl, ssrs-2012

I have a report with a page break in it that I want to remove, but I don't know where the break is being added.  It could be on a table, a group, or I don't know where else.

I checked the tablix properties and group properties for each portion of the report to see if "add a page break before" or "add a page break after" were checked, but didn't find anything.

Is there something i can search for in the RDL source code that will help?

Answer (score 0):

I usually find this occurs when the item (tablix, chart etc) will fit entirely on a new page but not entirely on the page where the control starts. For example if you have a header on page 1 but not on page 2 or you have a chart before your tablix and the tablix will not fit entirely on Page 1 but will fit entirely on Page 2 it chooses to put the tablix on Page 2 instead of half on Page 1 and half on Page 2.

If this is your issue try placing all elements inside another element (such as a rectangle, list or another tablix).

We would need more information to give a more specific answer. Can you post screens of the pages either side of the elusive page break?

Answer (score 0):

I was exporting to report type Web Archive (MHTML) and the page break was coming from the interactive height of the report.  Once I set it to zero I no longer got the page breaks.